# How to automatically generate parameter assignations in class constructors in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Does anyone know how to save typing in PhpStorm when you create a class constructor and you want to assign all the parameters to the respective class fields? I write it by hand now and I can do it quite quickly with the autocomplete feature, yet it is still a very tedious process.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    private $param1; 
    private $param2;
    private $param3;    

    public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3) {
          // Can I somehow automatically generate the following lines:
          //
          // $this->param1 = $param1;
          // $this->param2 = $param2;
          // $this->param3 = $param3;
          //
          //?
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use **"Initialize fields"** intention. For that: place caret on one of the parameters and invoke QuickFix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or by clicking on light bulb icon).

[image]

Comment: Genius! Worth noting that this will also generate `private $param1;`, `private $param2;` etc. if you don't have those yet

Comment: What if the context menu is not showing at all? I've posted the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401258/phpstorm-initialize-fields-context-menu-not-showing

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to have PhpStorm generate the constructor too you can go to Code -> Generate -> Constructor. This will take care of inserting the parameters you want as well as their initialization.

Or press `Alt+Insert` and choose `Constructor...`

Answer (score 4):

If you move the cursor to the word '__constructor', within a second or two a lightbulb pops up. when you press it you get an option "Initialize properties". If you select that option a popup appears where you can specify for which argument you want to create and assign a property.

[[image: Lightbulb[1]]]
[image: Argument popup]