# PhpStorm Initialize Fields context menu not showing

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have recently uninstalled (also deleted PhpStorm ~/Library/*/PhpStorm2019.1 files) and reinstalled the IDE (2019.1.2) from scratch. I am on a Mac with Mojave 10.14.5. This was due to the fact the Material Theme UI screwed up my themes.

When I started working and noticed that my beloved initialize fields option is no longer showing. I've been using initialize fields for a very long time and I can't explain what is causing it not to show. The whole context menu is not showing at all.

I'm referencing the below Question and Answer link because this is explaining exactly how I've been using the init fields option. [How to automatically generate parameter assignations in class constructors in PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487319/how-to-automatically-generate-parameter-assignations-in-class-constructors-in-ph)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the command show up when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and begin typing it's name? Is it just not showing up for the intentions menu? Is the file recognized as a class file?

Comment: forgot to mention, I am on a Mac (I've updated the description). I have tried Cmd+Shift+a but that is a shortcut for something else.

Comment: @Radu did you configure the path to your PHP executable in PHPStorm `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP`? Check your key bindings in PHPStorm for the bound key combination, `Settings -> Keymap` In the keymap panel expand `Other` and find `Show Intention Actions` to determine the key combination used. Ensure the cursor is currently in the constructor arguments when pressing the key combo.

Comment: Also ensure your PHP intentions are enabled, `Settings -> Editor -> Intentions`, In the intentions panel, find PHP, add a check to the desired intentions *(Initialize Fields)*, or check PHP to enable all of them.

Comment: @fyrye verified everything you said and all check ok. what else could it be? ..

Comment: Does the [lightbulb](https://imgur.com/8VJhbys) show up at all when you put the cursor into the constructor arguments and wait a second?  Ensure `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show intention bulb` is enabled. The only other thing I can think of is a corrupted or incorrect [previous profile files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs). Potentially a disabled or conflicting plugin. I would try a complete uninstall and reinstall again and test without changing anything.

Comment: Another option to try without uninstalling, close PHPStorm and any running subprocesses, rename the current profile "configuration" and "caches" files directories,  and launch PHPStorm afterward, to force PHPStorm to regenerate them.

Comment: I've set a new (different) project in the same PhpStorm installation and for that one the ```initialize fields``` option works. I'll take a look on what the differences are between the two projects in terms of plugins installed and settings. I'll get back.

Comment: Interesting, you may also want to try invalidating the caches (`File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`) of the non-functional project and try after PHPStorm finishes re-indexing. Keep in mind this will purge the local development history. Also check the event logs (`View -> Tool WIndows -> Event Log`) to ensure there are no errors/warnings. A plugin crashing may prevent other things from working.

Comment: cache clean and disabling all installed plugins still didn't solved the issue. ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs when a portion of the application code (ex: vendor/*app_modules*) is added to the **Excluded Directories list** (Preferences | Directories). This causes the inspections functionality, amongst others (for example unused `use` statements are no longer highlighted with grey, phpmd, phpcs notices and warnings are no longer displayed, sonarlint no longer shows analysis on the current file) to stop working as expected.

[image]

In my case the vendor modules were automatically added to the Excluded Directories list because of the directives defined in the .gitignore file (this happens when the project is created in PhpStorm).

```
# .gitignore file sample directive
vendor/
```

After removing each entry from the excluded list the inspections, phpmd and phpcs warnings, sonarlint analysis and everything else start working again.

Comment: *"...because of the directives defined in the .gitignore file..."* Well, you have resolved you issue so it does not really matter... but  IDE does NOT auto-exclude folders from .gitignore or alike (unless some other plugin did it). In PHP projects .. such exclusion would usually be caused by Composer integration settings. P.S. Why would you keep your code under `vendor` is unknown to me. That folder should be for 3rd party libraries where you do not need to edit anything yourself (at least that's the standard usage for such folder).

Comment: what do you mean by, "it does not really matter"? this may become helpful for others who may experience the same issues + @fyrey has added some valuable advices that may become handy. Isn't this the purpose of this platform?

Comment: regarding "Why would you keep your code under vendor", in Magento 2 development you can break your custom implementation in smaller modules that are hosted in separate repos and are pulled via composer.

Comment: *"you can break your custom implementation in smaller modules that are hosted in separate repos and are pulled via composer. "* This means that such module is somehow (semi-) independent from the rest and it can be developed separately (e.g. separate project; stored somewhere else etc) and pulled into main only when needed. Surely, what you have there is more convenient. It's just in general I would keep/treat stuff from `vendor` as "read only" and organize your project/setup somehow differently where all "editable" code is stored outside of such "ignored" folders.

Comment: It may have been an Additional Content Root in PhpStorm (the actual module code; would be a separate node in Project View panel). With such organisation you would never faced the issue as your *editable* code would not be located in excluded/ignored `vendor` folder.

Comment: *"what do you mean by, "it does not really matter"?"* 1) You have a working solution ... and it may be easier for you to work with what you already have/familiar with than "properly" organizing your code/setting up the IDE (as writing a library and using it as dependency at the same time is more convenient in the same project rather than separate/complex setup). Maybe a stuff like this will help: https://johannespichler.com/developing-composer-packages-locally/ 2) Not everybody wants to hear about other setups ("it works for me as is, so why bother" -- heard it quite a few times when commentin